# How can I get the values from Dropdown list in MsExcel?

Tags: excel

I have some values in a DropDown list. For eg, Cat, Dog, Goat, Lion, Elephant. I want to copy all the values and paste it in a single column.

Is it possible?

Comment: Select the drop down, you will see the formula of the drop down. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Go to Data tab, click Data Validation, go to Settings tab, copy Source. Paste into Word to remove commas and put into multiple lines. Then paste back into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Data > Data Validation (uder tool Data tools group). In the data validation window under Settings find 'Source:'.

In Source you might see values with separated by commas which would be your list or you might have something like this '=Sheet1!$F$3:$F$43', in which case you need to go to the sheet and look at the column to find the list values. In my case it I would look in Sheet1 in column F and you should see the values from the dropdown list there